# c++ - problem with memory in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, ncurses

I am currently learning about threads in c++ at uni and I have this small project involving ncurses - bouncing balls. I want the balls to spawn untill I press 'x'. After I press the button, it quits but it also shows something about memory protection violation.

When I use gdb, after pressing 'x', it says:

Thread 1 "p" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6e6b3c1 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff71c2c40 , 
    bytes=bytes@entry=28) at malloc.c:3612

The problem may be in the for loop but I am not sure.

There is the code I've written:

```
#include "window.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <atomic>

Window *window;
std::atomic<bool> run(true);


void exit() {
    while(run) {
        char z = getch();
        if(z == 'q') run = false;
    }
}

void ballFunction(int a) {
    int nr = a;
    while (run && window->balls[nr]->counter < 5) {
        usleep(50000);
        window->balls[nr]->updateBall();
    }
    window->balls[nr]->x = -1;
    window->balls[nr]->y = -1;
} 

void updateWindow2() {
    while(run) {
        usleep(50000);
        window->updateWindow();
    }
    delete window;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    window = new Window();

    int i = 0;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::thread threadWindow(updateWindow2);
    std::thread threadExit(exit);

    while(run = true) {
         window->addBall();
         threads.push_back(std::thread(ballFunction, i));
         i++;
         sleep(1);
    }

    threadWindow.join();
    threadExit.join();

    for(int j=2; j<i+2; j++) {
        threads[j].join();
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

---

```
#include "window.h"
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

Window::Window()
{
    initWindow();
}

Window::~Window()
{
    endwin(); 
}

void Window::initWindow()
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(FALSE); 
    clear();
    refresh();
}

void Window::addBall()
{
    Ball *ball = new Ball(this->ballCounter++);
    this->balls.push_back(ball);
}

void Window::updateWindow()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<ballCounter; i++)
    {
        if(balls[i]->update())
        {
            clear(balls[i]->yy, 
                balls[i]->xx);
            drawBall(balls[i]->y,
                 balls[i]->x);
        }
    }
    refresh();
}

void Window::clear(int y, int x)
{
    mvprintw(y, x, " ");
}

void Window::drawBall(int y, int x)
{
    mvprintw(y, x, "o"); 
}
```

Comment: Big surprise: It's possible to debug threads and see their call stack in most reasonable C++ IDE's. It's even possible with lower level debugging tools like GDB.

Comment: What does the `Window` class look like? Calling `addBall` in one thread while accessing `balls[nr]` in others can be bad.

Comment: Not your bug, but `void updateWindow2()` is an unconventional place to  `delete window;` It will raise fewer eyebrows if you move it to the end of `main` so that it lines up better with `window = new Window();`.

Comment: To add up to @user4581301 's comment. It's probably a bad idea to use `new` and `delete` manually in your code. You should have a look at [c++ standards dynamic memory management facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). These are guaranteed to be _thread safe_.

Comment: As @1201ProgramAlarm asked I have added Window class code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have one thread adding to the `balls` vector while other threads are reading from it.

When `addBall` calls `push_back`, if the vector capacity is not large enough new memory will be allocated, the existing objects moved or copied to the new block, and the old memory freed.  When this happens, the threads running `ballFunction` can write to memory that is no longer allocated.  This results in Undefined Behavior, including the segmentation fault you encounter.

You need to use some form of mutex, or ensure the `balls` vector has sufficient space allocated (using `balls.reserve(more_elements_than_youll_ever_create)`).

On an unrelated note, your main `while` loop will never terminate, because you have an assignment rather than a comparison as the condition (use `while (run)` or `while (run == true)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explains some things - I really appreciate that. One last question: do you suggest to use balls.reserve in any particular part of the program?